# Errors when trying to generate a signed apk

Tags: android

I added facebooklogin in app, it works correctly. But when generating a signed apk, it complains that there is no translation into Portuguese of `<string name = "fb_login_protocol_scheme"> 11111 </ string>` Below the error:

> Error:(4) Error: "fb_login_protocol_scheme" is not translated in "pt"
>   (Portuguese) [MissingTranslation]

But if I put it also in the /pt strings is returned this error:

> Error: (91) Error: Resources referenced from the manifest can not vary
>   by configuration (except for version qualifiers, e.g. -v21.) Found
>   variation in en [ManifestResource]

Gradle:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.16.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.23.+'
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it's the best thing to do, but this worked for me.

Gradle module app:

```
   buildTypes {
        release {
.....
            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
            }
        }
    }
```